# Gratis JS component to visualize the importance of parts within a whole

Tags: gratis, javascript

[Updtae] Since no one replied to my request for an AngularJs component, I will settle for any kind of JS - Vure, JQuery, plain old JS, anything else which I can show and manipulate in the browser...

---

I am looking for a gratis JS component.

Let’s imagine that I want to buy a car …

What’s the first thing that’s important to me? Let’ say price:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+  
|                           price                              |  
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But, mileage is also important:

```
+----------------------------+---------------------------------+
|           price            |        mileage                  |  
+----------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Looks like they are 50/50 split by default, but maybe I care less about initial purchase cost, as a good mileage will save me more when I look at total cost of ownership.

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
|     price   |                mileage                         |  
+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I want a component that will let me add (and remove) components of interest, and also let me give weighting/importance to them.

In the initial drawing, I had only price : 100%.

Then I added mileage, which defaulted to 50:50%.

But I want to be able to grab a drag handle with my mouse and move that dividing line (while the component shows me the weighting (percentage) for each constituent part).

And then, of course, I want to add running cost, such as maintenance and insurance, etc, adding, removing, renaming and adjusting the weighting of components until I am satisfied.

Comment: So it's not only about visualization but also about built-in editing of that visualization. Did I get that right?

Comment: People do awesome stuff with D3 https://d3js.org/, for example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961 but I am not familiar with it (and I'm not a JS developer)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas (+1)  I am aware of D3, of course, and that does look good. I just have to figure out how to drag the sliders